# Como retirar 1 elemento do vector de labels

Tags: java, array

```
Label[] posi={textf99, textf00, textf01, textf02, textf03, textf04, textf05, textf06, textf07, 
            textf08, textf09, textf10b, textf11, textf12, textf13, textf14, textf15, textf16, textf17, 
            textf18, textf19, textf20b, textf21b, textf22, textf23, textf24, textf25, textf26, textf27, 
            textf28, textf29, textf30b, textf31b, textf32b, textf33, textf34, textf35, textf36, textf37, 
            textf38, textf39, textf40b, textf41b, textf42b, textf43b, textf44, textf45, textf46, textf47, 
            textf48, textf49, textf50b, textf51b, textf52b, textf53b, textf54b, textf55, textf56, textf57, 
            textf58, textf59, textf60b, textf61b, textf62b, textf63b, textf64b, textf65b, textf66, textf67, 
            textf68, textf69, textf70b, textf71b, textf72b, textf73b, textf74b, textf75b, textf76b, textf77, 
            textf78, textf79, textf80b, textf81b, textf82b, textf83b, textf84b, textf85b, textf86b, textf87b, 
            textf88, textf89, textf90b, textf91b, textf92b, textf93b, textf94b, textf95b, textf96b, textf97b, 
            textf98b};
```

como retiro por exemplo a label  textf85b do array?

Comment: `Label[indicedesejado] =  null` isso é o mais proximo de remover um item de um array de objetos.

Comment: deve ser posi[indicedesejado] = null ou nao

Comment: sim, deve ser `posi` mesmo, e vc nao remove o indice, so anula a posicao onde o objeto se encontra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concordo com a resposta anterior onde a melhor opção seria usar uma lista. Porém, não será possível simplesmente converter usando o Arrays.asList diretamente.

```
    List<Label> list = Arrays.asList(posi);
    list.remove(label);
```

Isso vai gerar uma exceção: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.
O que diz a documentação do 'asList':

*"This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based"*

É como se você pudesse usar como consulta, pra listar, mas pra manipular como List não dá pois na verdade é como se por trás ainda fosse um array.

Pra ficar correto você precisa realmente criar um List:

```
    Label l0 = new Label("textf00");
    Label l1 = new Label("textf01");
    Label l2 = new Label("textf02");
    Label l3 = new Label("textf03");
    Label l4 = new Label("textf04");

    Label[] posi = { l0, l1, l2, l3, l4 };

    List<Label> list = new ArrayList<Label>(Arrays.asList(posi));

    list.remove(l1);
```

Answer (score 0):

O tamanho de um array não pode ser alterado, portanto um novo array tem que ser criado. Em seguida se copia os elementos anteriores ao do índice a ser removido e os elementos posteriores a esse índice.
Existem várias possibilidades, aqui algumas:

A mais antiga, usando `System.arraycopy` ((muito) antigamente podia causar crash da JVM):

```
Label[] remover(int indice, Label[] original) {
    // TODO validação do indice
    Label[] resultado = new Label[original.length-1];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, resultado, 0, indice);
    System.arraycopy(original, indice+1, resultado, indice, resultado.length-indice);
    return resultado;
}
```

em contraste usando `Stream`:

```
Label[] remover(int indice, Label[] original) {
    // TODO validação do indice
    return IntStream.concat(IntStream.range(0, indice), 
                            IntStream.range(indice+1, original.length))
                    .mapToObj(i -> original[i])
                    .toArray(Label[]::new);
}
```

ou

```
Label[] remover(int indice, Label[] original) {
    // TODO validação do indice
    return Stream.concat(
        Arrays.stream(original, 0, indice),
        Arrays.stream(original, indice+1, original.length)
        ).toArray(Label[]::new);
}
```

Sem `Stream` usando uma `ArrayList`, em minha opinião, a forma mais fácil de ser entendida:

```
Label[] remover(int indice, Label[] original) {
    // TODO validação do indice
    var lista = new ArrayList<>(List.of(original));  // ou ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(original));
    lista.remove(indice);
    return lista.toArray(new Label[0]);
}
```